# Single `when` clause with multiple `then` clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case-when

How to use same `WHEN` clause with multiple `THEN` cases e.g:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.test)=2 THEN t2.costs/2 ELSE t2.costs END costs,
CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.test)=2 THEN t2.CIR/2 ELSE t2.CIR END CIR,
CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.test)=2 THEN t2.CPV/2 ELSE t2.CPV END CPV
```

Is it possible to have one `WHEN` clause, since in all cases it is same?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible, as you need to evaluate the condition for each column value.

Comment: Please use the backticks to distinguish code from normal language. It was looking as a very bad english :-)

Comment: It looks like you are dividing a value by the number of times it appears in your result set. Is that correct?

Comment: i want to divide a column by 2 if count is equal to 2 otherwise nothing

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.test)=2 THEN t2.costs/2 ELSE t2.costs END costs,
CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.test)=2 THEN t2.CIR/2 ELSE t2.CIR END CIR,
CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.test)=2 THEN t2.CPV/2 ELSE t2.CPV END CPV
```

All case statement expressions seem to generate a new column value, and hence can't be used under a single `case-when` clause.

And as per documentation, for each of the expression's value, you have to use a `when` clause.

```
CASE COUNT(t2.test)
     WHEN 2 THEN t2.costs/2 
     WHEN 3 THEN some_other_expression_here
     ELSE t2.costs 
END costs,
CASE COUNT(t2.test)
     WHEN 2 THEN t2.CIR/2 
     WHEN 3 THEN another_expression_here
     ELSE t2.CIR
END CIR,
CASE another_case_expression
     WHEN ...
     ELSE ...
END as value_alias_name
```

You can't just check a single `when` at one place and use it at multiple column expressions.

**Refer to**:

1. [*MySQL: CASE Syntax*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html)
2. [*MySQL: CASE Operator*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of evaluating for non-nulls (existing id) in several tables in sequence, joined with LEFT OUTERs.  The first table with a matching row assigns the 'phase' of the query row.

```
CASE COALESCE(a.id, p.id, f.id, g.id, c.id) 
WHEN a.id THEN 'Arb' 
WHEN p.id THEN '3' 
WHEN f.id THEN '2' 
WHEN g.id THEN '1' 
WHEN c.id THEN '0' 
ELSE '0' 
END as phase
```